# Unhandled exception type Exception

Tags: java, exception, enums

This is a simplified class that describes my problem:

```
public class Main {

    enum Test{
        First(method()){ // Unhandled exception type Exception
            // ...
        };

        Test(Object obj){
            //...
        }
    }

    static Object method() throws Exception{
        // ...
        if (someCondition){
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }
}
```

Above `someCondition` depends on device and some situations and I can not decide in about it now, also as you can see, I do not want to catch `Exception` in `method`.

Comment: what's the question? you don't want it throw? i think java does initialization when the first time you reference to the class, so it could look like throwing exception in random places.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr It is a compile error.

Comment: oh, yeah. since it's checked exception so it's not going to compile. you need to wrap it over a `RuntimeException` to allow it throw silently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  It is a compilation error.

No.  There is no special syntax to deal with this.

> I do not want to catch Exception in method.

Unfortunately if you throw a checked exception, *it has to be caught* further up the call stack.  That is a fundamental design principal for the Java language, and one that the compiler enforces strictly.

In this case, there is no way to catch the checked exception.  Hence, if you are going to call a method in enum constant parameter (as per your code), the method cannot throw a checked exception<sup>1</sup>.

Here is a possible workaround, though this is probably a bad idea:

```
public class Main {

    enum Test{
        First(methodCatchingException()){
            // ...
        };

        Test(Object obj){
            //...
        }
    }

    static Object method() throws Exception{
        // ...
        if (someCondition){
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    static Object methodCatchingException() {
        try {
            return method();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SomeRuntimeException("the sky is falling!", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to look at this problem is to ask yourself what *should* happen with the exception if the compiler let you write that ... and an exception was thrown?  Where would it go?

- You can't catch it ... because the `enum` initialization is like a `static` initialization.
- If the Java runtime completely ignored the thrown exception, that would be really bad.
- If the Java runtime crashed, then the model of checked exceptions is broken.

So, what this is saying to me is that the Java language design is right, the Java compiler is right ... and the real problem here is in your application *design*:

- You should not be propagating a checked exception here. If an exception occurs in this context it is categorically NOT a recoverable error.
- Maybe it is inadvisable to use an enum for this ... because of the potential for non-recoverable initialization errors.

(Note that if this method call terminates due to an unchecked exception, it will turn it into an `ExceptionInInitializerError`.  In addition, the JVM will mark the `enum` class as uninitializable, and will throw an `NoClassDefFoundError` if your application attempts to use it; e.g. via `Class.forName(...)`.)

---

I assume that `Exception` is used here for illustration purposes.  It is a bad thing to declare methods as `throws Exception` or to `throw new Exception(...)`

---

<sup>1 - I had a look at the JLS for something to back this up.  As far as I can tell, the spec does not mention this situation.  I'd have expected to see it listed in [JLS 11.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3).  However, it is clear that a compiler cannot allow a checked exception to propagate at that point as it would "break" the model of how checked exceptions work.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your attention, throwing `Exception` was for simplifying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to be throwing a checked exception here (which is what `Exception` is).  The reason:  you're invoking the call of `method` inside of the constructor of `Test`.  There's really not a clean way to deal with it.

While the obvious choice here is to switch to `RuntimeException`, I want you to reconsider throwing the exception in the first place.  Since your enum will only ever have `First` declared in it, does it *really* make sense for it to throw an exception when it's being *instantiated*?  Personally, I don't think it does; whatever dangerous operation it's doing should be deferred until you want to invoke it, and *then* would you want to throw your exception.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I add only one `enum` to  reduce complexity.